# Dynamic component adding in angular2

Tags: angular

In angular 2 my app has the following

```
<my-app>

<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>

</my-app>
```

At some point of time the system will send notification so, it has to add the notification component to "". How can we achieve this. Which concept we use in angular 2

```
<my-app>

<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>
<item></item>

<notification></notification>

</my-app>
```

Comment: You should use hidden property to conditionally display an element; for more information take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html#!#ng-show

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `ngIf`.  `ngIf` allows you to display content based on a condition.  This can either be an expression or simply a boolean.

As an example, you can set the notification to display only when a variable called 'notify' is true, or else it will not display.  Place this in your HTML template for that example:

```
<notification *ngIf="notify"></notification>
```

Change if it's displayed by changing the variable in your component.ts file.

```
export class MyComponent {

    notify = false;

    displayNotificaiton() {
        this.notify = true;
    }

}
```

You may also want to read over the ngIf documentation.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html